# once detected a qrcode, track the position whilemoving camera

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code

Once detected a qrcode using zxing, I need to trace its x and y position while I move the camera (considered a cartesian reference system in 2 dimensions x and y) .
Is it possible? Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's possible.

If the QR code includes the recommended [quiet zone](http://google.com/search?q=qr+code+quiet+zone) and the input image doesn't contain much in the way of rapid movements or motion blur, then all you need to do is crop the image to a smaller region near the last known location of the QR code, apply a threshold filter and look for a square block in the results.

If that fails, pass the whole image back to zxing.

If you like you can also check the orientation of the QR code by searching for the registration marks in three corners.

Comment: how can we get the coordinates of registration marks in the image?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja If you apply a filer that calculates the minimum intensity values in the local vicinity of each pixel, the whole QR code should appear as a black square. Finding the corners of this square should be fairly easy. To find the registration marks, look at the intensity values along the two diagonals, where they will appear as a tell-tale "dot-dash-dot" pattern at both ends of one diagonal and at one end of the other. [Here's an illustration of what I mean.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zCLXC.png)